# Marketing definition deployment takes forever

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

When I access Experience Analytics from the Launchpad and click on the goals report, I get a message saying "no data to display".

After some searching, it seems that I should deploy marketing definitions (goals) in case I upgraded the site, which is my case.

I went to Launchpad -> Control panel -> Analytics -> Deploy Marketing Definitions, then I selected "goals" only and clicked on "Deploy".

My problem is the deployment is still working for 3 or 4 days now, and I can't see issues in the log files, is there a way to know how much time it will take? or how I can know if something wrong is happening?

Comment: Can you tell us which version you upgraded from and to, please?

Comment: From Sitecore 7.5 into 8.1

Comment: can you rebuild reporting database https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database ?

Comment: Should I wait until the marketing deployment finish, or should I stop it and do the rebuild?

Comment: wait to have all the information

Comment: Do you know how much time it takes usually to deploy marketing definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the Goal Definitions table and it seems no more updates are coming to this table, I opened a ticket for Sitecore support and the issue is related to a UI bug.

following reply from Sitecore support:

The issue appears when the Deploy button is pressed, but the Taxonomies are not deployed (for example, only Goals are deployed).
As a result, the processing is finished, but the UI will still display the spinning icon until the window is closed.

The reference number for the bug is 107306 for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Marketing definitions include things like campaigns, goals, outcomes and assets. You can see them in the Marketing Control Panel:

[image: marketing definitions]

You'll almost never have more than 200 marketing definitions in total—there are a number of predefined campaigns, goals and outcomes, and you can add more custom definitions by hand. Due to the relatively low number of items, their deployment will normally take just a few seconds. If it takes longer than several minutes, something has gone wrong. Check Sitecore logs for errors to see where the problem lies.

If the deployment process has hung up and you can't see any errors, then you should start from scratch. Restart Sitecore and use the "Deploy marketing definitions" feature once again. Don't worry about data consistency—if a marketing definition has already been deployed, it will simply be overwritten.

To learn more about the mechanics of marketing definition deployment, see this answer:
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1963/104

Note that to see the complete Experience Analytics reports after you've deployed marketing definitions, you may need to [**rebuild the Reporting database**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database).